# Using "right away" at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: style

Is it okay in English to use the adverbial phrase "right away" at the beginning of a sentence?

For example, is it okay instead of

> I will hug him right away.

to say

> Right away I will hug him.

or is it not making any sense in English?

Comment: Right away, my answer was yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use *right away* at the beginning of a sentence. However, as an introductory phrase, it should be followed by a comma:

In your example sentence it would also be constructed similarly:

> Right away, I will hug him.

However, that sounds strange. Using *right away* at the start of a sentence isn't normally used with the future tense. It's commonly used with the past or present tense—and, if I think about it, a phrase that involves a helper verb:

> Right away, I **could see he needed** a hug.
>   Right away, I **wanted to** hug him.
>   Right away, I **gave him** a hug.

I can't explain exactly why this would be the case.